# How to Generate XML file from Save As Dialog box using MVC

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have to generate a XML file which have details about its particular table row from a button, and will prompt a Save As dialog to User to sve the file.

I am a beginner in MVC and ASP.Net, but with the help of many blogs or examples available, I was able to create below things but I'm getting many build errors when I run or if I don't get the build errors then the button doesn't do anything.

I referred this article to implement but not able to get much results :
http://nraykov.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/show-save-as-dialog-with-content-disposition-response-header/

Let me know if m miising any detail or u need some more information.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing it's the ActionLink that doesn't create the correct URL for you.

try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manifest", "Export", "Deployment", null, new {@class = "button"})
```

Comment: I changed the ActionLink it is now generating the correct URL.. finally its calling the Action.. but when I click it doesn't do anything.. just goes to blank screen...

Comment: the actionlink does a http-get but your action requires a post with the attribute: [HttpPost].

Comment: You're right!! I changed the Action to HTTPGet and its calling the function, but now it takes me to null and return to "Index" view everytime... what should I do so it should prompt the "Save As" dialog?

Comment: then it's not in your cache probably. try creating new instance of DeploymentDto and setting it manually in the controller.